# How do I limit the amount of times an address can interact with a function?

Tags: solidity

I would like to know how do I limit the amount of times an address can interact with a function, as in saving the amount of times an address interacted with the function as an uint256 so that I could reset it to 0 with another function, thanks!

Comment: Make a mapping with addresses as keys and an integer as a value. Any time they interact the contract checks if they have reached their limit. If they haven't the code runs and the counter goes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single function, you can use a `mapping` where the key is the user address and the value is the amount of interactions.

If you need to expand the functionality to track separate interactions with multiple functions, the key should be a combination of the user address and the function selector. You can combine them for example in a `keccak256` hash.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint256 constant MAX_INTERACTIONS = 10;
    mapping(address => uint256) interactionCount;

    modifier limit {
        require(interactionCount[msg.sender] < MAX_INTERACTIONS);
        interactionCount[msg.sender]++;
        _;
    }

    function foo() external limit {
        // your implementation
    }

    function resetLimit(address user) external {
        // TODO you might want to restrict this function only to an authorized address
        interactionCount[user] = 0;
    }
}
```